# how to divide value of one group with rest in dplyr

Tags: r

I have dataframe like following

```
fund_name       Industry     quantity      month
 ABC              IT           20          201704
 ABC              IT           20          201704
 ABC              Industrials  30          201704
 ABC              Auto         40          201704
 ABC              Pharma       50          201704
 DEF              IT           20          201704 
 DEF              Auto         35          201704
 DEF              Auto         35          201704
 DEF              Pharma       40          201704
```

What I want to calculate is composition of industry percentage of quantity.
e.g. For fund ABC IT industry is contributing to 40/(40+30+20+50) = 0.28 i.e 28% in month 201704

Desired dataframe should look like this.

```
fund_name       Industry       quantity                  month
 ABC              IT           40/(40+30+20+50)          201704
 ABC              Industrials  30/(40+30+20+50)          201704
 ABC              Auto         40/(40+30+20+50)          201704
 ABC              Pharma       50/(40+30+20+50)          201704
 DEF              IT           20/(20+70+40)             201704 
 DEF              Auto         70/(20+70+40)             201704
 DEF              Pharma       40/(20+70+40)             201704
```

I have tried below but it gives me only sum of quantity.

```
final_MF %>% 
   group_by(fund_names,Month,Industry) %>% 
   summarise(total_quant = sum(Quantity)) %>% 
   as.data.frame()
```

how can I achieve this in dplyr?

Comment: You mean groupby `fund_name`?

Comment: group by fund_name,Industry and month

Comment: If you are grouping by fund_name, Industry, and month based on the example you showed, it gives only 1.  I am not following the logic of denominator

Comment: I am not sure your expected is correct.  Perhaps `df1 %>% group_by(fund_name) %>% mutate(newquant = quantity/sum(quantity))`

Comment: @akrun When I do this `df1 %>% group_by(fund_name,industry,month) %>% mutate(newquant = quantity/sum(quantity))` does not give me what is intended.

Answer (score 1):

One of several ways:

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="fund_name       Industry     quantity      month
ABC              IT           20          201704
ABC              Industrials  30          201704
ABC              Auto         40          201704
ABC              Pharma       50          201704
DEF              IT           20          201704 
DEF              Auto         35          201704
DEF              Pharma       40          201704")
df

library(dplyr)
want<-select(
  mutate(
    left_join(df,
            df %>%
                  group_by(fund_name) %>%
                  summarize(quantity_sum=sum(quantity)),
                by="fund_name"),
    quantity=quantity/quantity_sum),
  -quantity_sum)
want
```

Answer (score 1):

Following R code got me what I was looking for

```
industry_composition <- final_reliance_MF %>% 
   group_by(fund_names,Industry,Month) %>% 
   summarise(total_quant = sum(Quantity)) %>% 
   group_by(fund_names,Month) %>% 
   mutate(perc = (total_quant/sum(total_quant))*100) %>% 
   as.data.frame()
```